# Visual Studio 2013, run one test separated via shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I hope some one has an idea why Ctrl+R, T is not working in VS2013 anymore.
Previously (VS2012) when I hit the shortcut, and I had my cursor in a test, it only runs the test.
At the website of Microsoft it says exactly how I should expect it should work.
It says:

```
Ctrl + R, then press T

This runs the tests in the current scope. That is, it runs the 
current test method, all the tests in the current test class, or 
all the tests in the namespace, respectively.
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms182470.aspx#RunTestsFromTestProject

However in VS2013 it runs all the tests in the current file.
When I use the Test Explorer it runs correctly the only selected test...

I have the following extensions installed:

- Productivity Power Tools 2013
- Xunit.net runner for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013
- Chutzpah Test Adapter for the Test Explorer
- Chutzpah Test Runner Context Menu Extension

Comment: Don't have R# installed?

Comment: No R# (Resharper for people who don't understand) is installed

Comment: I have just tried it on my instance is 2013 and it works fine. If you go to `Tools -> Options -> Keyboard` and in the 'Press shortcut keys' box type Ctrl R + T, what shortcut is it assigned to?

Comment: Shortcut currently used by: TestExplorer.RunAllTestsInContext (Ctrl+R, T (Global))

Comment: Can you double check if the cursor is at the right location? If you have your cursor at any location within the class/namespace scope instead of the testmethod scope then all the tests in the class/namepsace will be executed.

Comment: Hi @allen Thx for your reply. The cursor is on the right place. It worked before (VS2012) but in 2013 it runs all tests in the class. So no check if the cursor is within a method or within the class...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, its a bug in the xUnit testrunner.
I tested with NUnit and it works as expected.

On xUnit.net is a bugreport. 
Link: http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9901

Edit:
Issue is solved in version 0.99.2